# What technique is recommended for analysis of repeated-measured-data by using R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have a repeated measured dataset, which confused me a lot. I'm a newer to statistics.

The experiment design:

Feeding a kind of small animal with **Food type** (three) ***Food concentration** (High Medium Low) and cultured at different **temperature**(three), and I measured the size with **time** (six times).

The dataset:

```
**foodtype** **concentration** **temperature** **time** **size**
Food 1  High    13  18  1.852885
Food 2  Medium  13  18  1.55763
Food 3  Medium  20  6   1.46956
Food 1  Low     13  24  1.57598
Food 2  Low     27  0   0.95645
Food 3  High    20  0   1.17581
Food 1  High    13  0   0.9945
Food 1  High    27  6   1.85493
Food 2  Medium  20  24  1.41863
Food 3  Low     27  0   0.67921
Food 3  Medium  20  6   1.42707
Food 1  High    27  6   2.06973
Food 3  High    13  30  1.98104
Food 3  Medium  13  6   1.54095
Food 1  High    27  0   1.09006
Food 2  Medium  13  12  1.89104
Food 1  High    20  12  1.80081
Food 1  Medium  27  24  0.95945
Food 3  High    13  6   1.94308
Food 1  Low     27  0   0.9548
Food 1  Low     13  24  1.60799
Food 2  Medium  27  0   0.86186
Food 1  Medium  13  18  2.04876
Food 2  Low     13  24  1.48339
Food 3  Low     20  0   0.88978
Food 2  High    27  12  0.99612
```

The data visualization:

[image: data visualization]

How should I analyze the three factors (**food types, food concentration, temperature**) effect on animal growth with **time**.

Comment: Where in these data and graphics is "animal growth" represented?  Are either of "diameter" or "size" related to the growth?  If so, how?

Comment: @whuber, Dear whuber, yes, in the dataset "size"=in the graph "diameter". I measured the diameter to present their growth with time. Do you have suggestions for me?

Comment: which analysis do you think appropriate e.g. Anova, regression or else. Propose  your model .